# Proof of result regarding simultaneous confidence statements

Tags: confidence-interval

In the book Applied multivariate statistical analysis by Johnson & Wichern I came across the following result:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from an $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution. Then simultaneously for all vectors $a$, the interval:
$\left(a^{'} \bar X  -\sqrt{\frac{p(n-1)}{n(n-p)}F_{p,n-p(\alpha)}a^{'}Sa},a^{'} \bar X  +\sqrt{\frac{p(n-1)}{n(n-p)}F_{p,n-p(\alpha)}a^{'}Sa} \right)$
will contain $a^{'}\mu$ with probability $1-\alpha$.

The proof states that the maximum of $t^2=max_{a}\left[\frac{n(a^{'}(\bar x-\mu))^2}{a^{'}Sa}\right]=T^2=n(\bar x-\mu)^{'}S^{-1}(\bar x-\mu)$. So that if  $T^{2}\leq c^{2}$ this implies $t^{2}\leq c^{2}
$ for every $a$.
This still makes sense to me but then it continues by saying that now it should follow that choosing the appropriate $c$ will give intervals which will contain $a^{'}\mu$ for all $a$ with probability $1-\alpha$.

I know how to derive this interval from the distribution of $T^{2}$ but it seems to me that this doesn't proof that the probability of all these intervals holding simultaneously is $1-\alpha$. It seems as if nothing is said with regard to the probability that all different intervals for different vectors $a$ hold simultaneously.  All you know from this is that any individual interval will have probability $p\geq 1-\alpha$ of containing the true parameter before the sample is selected, with equality holding only for the vector $a$ that maximizes $t^{2}$.

**Additional thought:**
If $A$ implies $B$ then $P(B)\geq P(A)$ So now take the event $A$ as $T^{2}\leq c^{2}$ which implies event $B=[\forall  a: t^{2}\leq c^{2}]$ and the theorem follows.
Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Well if the maximum is less than $c^2$, wouldn't all the rest also be less than that as well? The procedure is conservative, meaning that the probability that all linear combinations satisfy the inequality is actually higher.